# Create one row array from range (error handling)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I have a dynamic table with several columns including filenames.
Sometimes it happens that I only have one row but I still want to run the upcoming function.

The values are assigned like this:

```
arrFileNames = Range("Links[PDF_File]").Value
```

I receive a runtime error 13 in this line:

```
ReDim arrFilesExistence(1 To UBound(arrFileNames))
```

This happens because the the array is now only a one row range and thus get's saved as a string.

I tried to circumvent this by trying to redim but it does not seem to work:

```
If Range("Links[PDF_File]").Count = 1 Then
    arrFileNames = Array(arrFileNames)
    ReDim Preserve arrFileNames(1 To 1)
End If
```

I cannot seem to find a way. The workaround lets the array be a `UBound = 0` array.

Anyone with a working solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that the **range contains only one cell** then the value of such range is not array. So with `IsArray()` function we can check if value of a range is array and use `ReDim` to create space in our `arrFileNames`. It has then *one row and one column* and finally we assign the value to it. HTH

```
Dim data As Variant
Dim arrFileNames As Variant

data = Range("YourRangeName").value

If Not IsArray(data) Then
    ' data consists of one cell only
    ReDim arrFileNames(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    arrFileNames(1, 1) = data
Else
    arrFileNames = data
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on error resume next`

```
On Error Resume Next
arrFileNames = Range("Links[PDF_File]").Value
ReDim arrFilesExistence(1 To UBound(arrFileNames))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
ReDim arrFilesExistence(1 To 1)
End If
```